# Are righteous gentiles in a covenant with God?

Tags: talmud-gemara

Is there anything in the Talmud that discusses righteous Gentiles being in a covenant with God?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%96%D7%95%D7%98%D7%90_%D7%9B כוהניך - אלו צדיקי אומות העולם שהם כוהנים להקב״ה בעולם הזה כגון, אנטונינוס וחביריו. Your priests - these are the righteous gentiles who are the priests to Hashem in this world, such as Antoninus and his friends.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score -5):

All righteous Gentiles are in a covenant with G-d. See Rabbi Asher Meza [here](https://youtu.be/Cd03t090TnU).

Comment: Are you going to give us his address? His phone number? Or a link/reference to where he talks about this?

Comment: I would not recommend Rabbi Asher Meza in any way.It seems he goes a lot against Judaism,so many heretical statements and lies.In my view every righteous gentile must indeed convert to Judaism!

Comment: Asher Meza has a different view but he’s not going against the Law. Also I’ve never heard a rabbi say a gentile must convert.

Comment: @KamilLeviPyka He would agree that they should all convert. Nothing he says is heretical.

Comment: @magicker72 786 702-5711 his phone number. He talks about it [here](https://youtu.be/Cd03t090TnU)

Comment: @TurkHill I don't actually want his number. I was implying that you should source your claims better than "Person X".

Comment: @magicker72 I also left a link in that comment. I will also link my answer the the Youtube video where he talks about it.

Comment: Excuse me for invalidating your rabbi, but one of the purposes of down votes it to point out poor sources, and this is emphatically a poor source.

Comment: Also, the question was for a source from the Talmud, which this simply is not.

Comment: @Mordechai Would you like to debate him? His number is 786 702-5711